# Is it idiomatic to construct against `this`?

Tags: c++

When making a curses version of Snake, I found that the `this` pointer was bindable for reconstruction from inside an 'update' method.

The issue with this is that, although very convenient (saves having to rebind 'player' in a game object), it doesn't feel particularly idiomatic.

Using the snake as an example, we'd be destroying it and reconstructing it as we're inside a method call on the initial(?) snake.

Here's an example of rebinding `this` in some struct `A`:

```cpp
struct A
{
    int first;
    A(int first) : first(first){};
    void method(int i);
};

void A::method(int i)
{
    *this = i;
}
```

Comment: I definitely use that to share code between functions. Especially overloaded operators. Particularly when implementing copy and move operators/constructors. And sometimes when writing iterators sharing functionality between *preincrement* and *postincrement* operators.

Comment: *I* would use the `explicit` keyword to make this illegal unless explicitly asked for. Having this conversion being implicitly allowed is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's legal, but if I saw it I would question whether the author knew what they were doing: *Did they really mean to invoke `this->operator=()`? Surely there's a better way to do... whatever it is they're trying to do.*

In your case, `*this = i` is equivalent to `this->operator=(i)`. Since there's no `operator=(int)` defined, it uses the default assignment operator and the `A(int)` constructor to perform `this->operator=(A(i))`. The net effect is exactly the same as if you had written:

```
this->first = i;
```

*Why didn't they just assign to `first` directly?* I'd be asking.

If for some reason you do want all those steps, I'd at least make the implicit `A(int)` construction explicit:

```
*this = A(i);
```

Comment: On reading this code I'd assume it was one of those unfortunate cases where the compiler missed issuing a warning on code that obviously isn't doing what the programmer wanted.  And then on the code review I'd point out he wouldn't have had this problem if he had declared the single-arg constructor `explicit`.

Comment: Just for additional clarity, the intent was more-so the copy assignment and temporary destruction part of this answer. The implicit constructor call as a conversion was incidental. I'll add an edit to clarify. Otherwise, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

`*this = i;` implicitly constructs new instance of `A` as `A::A(int)` is not an `explicit` constructor and therefore creates the implicit conversion from `int` to `A`. `*this = i;` then calls default `A::operator=` with this new instance of `A` constructed from `i`. Then the new instance of `A` is destroyed.

So the code `*this = i;` is equivalent to `operator=(A(i));` in your case.

It's legal to do so, but the code readability suffers from such a big amount of implicit actions.

Answer (score 8):

You aren't destroying the object pointed to by `this`, you are calling it's `operator=`, which will copy `first` from a temporary initialised from `i`. You destroy the temporary after the assignment.

It might be clearer to write an `A& operator=(int)` which had the same effect.